# Using both <select>'s value AND text for ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I currently have this:

```
<div>
    <label for="market-type">Market Type</label>
    <select id="market-type" type="text" ng-model="tradingFee.market_type">
        <option value="stock">Stock Market</option>
        <option value="otc">OTC Market</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

which assigns the **selected option's value** to `tradingFee.market_type`. What I wish is to be able to do this plus assign the **selected option's text** to `tradingFee.market_type_human_friendly_text`, for example. **Only being able to do one of the assignments is not enough.** Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Use `ng-options` to create option tags from array of objects. Then can either bind `ng-model` to full object or use `ng-change` to update the other variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this, but not with this syntax. use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) so that the ng-model holds both value and display name.

In your controller set array of objects:

```
 $scope.marketType = [{id:"stock", displayName:"Stock Market"}, {id:"otc", displayName:"OTC Market"}];
```

and

```
<select id="market-type" type="text"
        ng-model="tradingFee.market_type" 
        ng-options="mt.displayName for mt in marketType track by mt.id">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Now the `ng-model` will have both id as well as value. i.e example:

`tradingFee.market_type` will be `{id:"otc", displayName:"Stock Market"}` if you select that specific item from the dropdown. With this you do not have to worry about maintaining 2 separate properties for displayName and id.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.marketType = [{
      id: "stock",
      displayName: "Stock Market"
    }, {
      id: "otc",
      displayName: "OTC Market"
    }];
    $rootScope.tradingFee = {
      market_type: {
        id: 'stock'
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <select id="market-type" type="text" ng-model="tradingFee.market_type" ng-options="mt.displayName for mt in marketType track by mt.id">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
  </select>
  {{ tradingFee.market_type }}


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use ng-change on your select to fire a custom event handler that sets the secondary value.

```
<select id="market-type" type="text" ng-model="tradingFee.market_type" 
   ng-change="updateSecondary()">
   <option value="stock">Stock Market</option>
   <option value="otc">OTC Market</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sets it from what though? Would need to parse DOM in controller which is not a preferred approach

Comment: You don't need to as you have the id and the list in your scope. There's an example which does exactly this here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-Get-selected-Text-and-Value-of-HTML-Select-DropDownList-using-ng-change.aspx